# Linear transformations same field

Tags: linear-algebra

Why should linear transformation involve vector spaces over same field?
definition of a linear transformation: 
Let $U$ and $V$ be $2$ vector spaces 'over the same field $K$'. So what happens if the vector spaces are described over two different fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, one of the demands you put on the transformation is this:

If $A$ is a linear transformation and $x\in U$, then, for every scalar $\alpha\in F$, we must have $A(\alpha x) = \alpha A(x)$

This demand requres that $\alpha$ is both an element of $U$'s field (otherwise, $\alpha x$ is not defined) and $V$'s field (otherwise, $\alpha A(x)$ is undefined)

Comment: then if the field of U is a subset of the field of V, the transformation would still be defined?

Comment: @samantha I think it would have to be a subfield, not just a subset. For example U as a space over the reals and V as a space over complex numbers should work.

Comment: alright. makes sense cheers!